# Enable comment box and make it required for rejection through path

Tags: trigger, approval-process

I have used a trigger to make the rejection comments mandatory while rejecting the record via the related list which works fine. However when i reject the record using path, it gives me an error- **There's a problem saving this record. You might not have permission to edit it, or it might have been deleted or archived. Contact your administrator for help.** 
I also need to have a comment box appear and make it mandatory when i reject the record through path too.

The trigger used is as follows:

```
trigger Reject_Comments on Account(before update) {
    Map<Id, Account> rejectedStatements = new Map<Id, Account>{};

    for (Account cur : Trigger.new) {
        Account oldCur = Trigger.oldMap.get(cur.Id);

        if (oldCur.Approval_Status__c != 'Rejected' && cur.Approval_Status__c == 'Rejected') {
            rejectedStatements.put(cur.Id, cur);
        }
    }

    if (!rejectedStatements.isEmpty()) {
        List<Id> processInstanceIds = new List<Id>{};

        for (Account curn : [
            SELECT (SELECT ID FROM ProcessInstances ORDER BY CreatedDate DESC LIMIT 1)
            FROM Account
            WHERE ID IN :rejectedStatements.keySet()
        ]) {
            processInstanceIds.add(curn.ProcessInstances[0].Id);
        }

        for (ProcessInstance pi : [
            SELECT
                TargetObjectId,
                (
                    SELECT Id, StepStatus, Comments
                    FROM Steps
                    WHERE StepStatus = 'Rejected'
                    ORDER BY CreatedDate DESC
                    LIMIT 1
                )
            FROM ProcessInstance
            WHERE Id IN :processInstanceIds
            ORDER BY CreatedDate DESC
        ]) {
            if ((pi.Steps[0].Comments == null || pi.Steps[0].Comments.trim().length() == 0)) {
                rejectedStatements.get(pi.TargetObjectId).addError('Please provide a rejection reason!');
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Could someone help me in the above requirement.

Comment: Are you using standard path from the lightning app builder?

Comment: Yes. I am using the standard path.

Comment: I think you won't be able to do this using a standard path.

Comment: Oh. okay Rahul.